# Google Maps API v3 resize event

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Using Maps API v3. As per Google documentation, if the map container is resized programmatically, the map resize event must be triggered manually.

Resize event: Developers should trigger this event on the map when the div changes size.

Therefore I am using:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

Which listener should I be using to update my markers based on the new bounds of the resized map container?

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'resize', function() {

    console.log(map.getBounds());
});
```

The above still shows the bounds before resizing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Whenever the map is resized, the bounds will chage. Therefore, you can use the `bounds_changed` event:

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
});
```

It has the following description:

> This event is fired when the viewport bounds have changed.

---

If you only want the event to be called after the map is resized, you can use a boolean variable to track whether the map has just been resized, like so:

```
var mapResized = false;
```

Then, whenever you trigger the `resize` function, you can set the `mapResized` variable to `true`. You can do so using a function:

```
function resizeMap(map) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    mapResized = true;
}
```

Then, in the `bounds_changed` event, you can only react to call if `mapResized` is true, and afterwards set `mapResized` to `false`:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    if (mapResized) {
        // react here
    }
    mapResized = false;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know the bounds_changed event, but that doesn't suit my needs, since bounds_changed is also called after a drag or a zoom change. I want to be able to do something only when I trigger that specific resize event.

Comment: Interesting solution. Does the "idle" event get fired after both a zoom change, a drag and a resize event? In which case I could be doing everything at the same place?

Comment: @MrUpsidown - I think the "idle" event is fired after dragging and zooming, but not after resizing.

Comment: That actually works. After resizing, dragging and zooming. I'll be doing everything there then. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MrUpsidown I am looking to trigger a API call which centers the page, if 'mapResized' is true. What would be the best method?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know when the bounds change, you need to listen for the "bounds_changed" event

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    console.log(map.getBounds());
});
```

If you only want the first bounds changed event after you trigger the resize event, you can use:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    console.log(map.getBounds());
});
```

right before you trigger the resize event.

Answer (score 1):

On Angular.js and IONIC I solved by insering this code after the **

```
declaration of var map = new google..... :
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', function () {
   google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
   var bounds = map.getBounds();
});
```